# I Don't know where is my codes problem (using structures in C)

Tags: c

The user will give a list of students and the code will save them in a file but the first line is not correct.
the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <comip.h>


#define MAX_STR_LEN 80

int main() {
    //creating file
    FILE *students_file;
    students_file = fopen("students_file.txt", "w");
    int students_num;
    puts("How many students do you have ? : ");
    scanf("%d", &students_num);
    struct students
    {
        char first_name[MAX_STR_LEN];
        char last_name[MAX_STR_LEN];
        char id[12];
        float average;
    };

    struct students *students = calloc(students_num, sizeof *students);

    fprintf(students_file, "number     id       firstname       lastname        average\n");
    for (int i = 1; i <= students_num; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter student #%d first name : ", i);
        scanf("%79s", students[i].first_name);
        printf("Please enter student #%d last name : ", i);
        scanf("%79s", students[i].last_name);
        printf("Please enter student #%d id : ", i);
        scanf("%79s", students[i].id);
        printf("Please enter student #%d average : ", i);
        scanf("%f", &students[i].average);
        fprintf(students_file, "#%d.\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %f\n", i, students[i].id,  students[i].first_name, students[i].last_name, students[i].average);
    }
    fclose(students_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Then its my input :

```
> How many students do you have ? :
3
Please enter student #1 first name : mani
Please enter student #1 last name : aghaie
Please enter student #1 id : 1383ma
Please enter student #1 average : 19.72
Please enter student #2 first name : arash
Please enter student #2 last name : hamidi
Please enter student #2 id : 1384ah
Please enter student #2 average : 14.27
Please enter student #3 first name : pourya
Please enter student #3 last name : ghorbani
Please enter student #3 id : 1382pg
Please enter student #3 average : 16.52
```

and this is the output

[image: Can anybody help me with that please?]

Comment: Well, what's the output you'd _expect_?

Comment: `scanf("%79s", students[i].id);` - your `id` is only size 12

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= students_num; i++)` Indexing in C is 0-based.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Copy&paste the actual output as text and format it as a code block, type the expectes output and format it in the same way. You should check the return value of `scanf` and all functions that may indicate errors. Compile your program with warnings and sanitizers enabled, see https://airbus-seclab.github.io/c-compiler-security/

Comment: I don't know if you will need an array of student records later, but the current program could use a single `struct students` because the values are no longer needed after writing to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out your code.  To be brief, the array index values you use are not actually in the proper range as the first array index should start at zero.

Refactoring your "for loop" from:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= students_num; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter student #%d first name : ", i);
        scanf("%79s", students[i].first_name);
        printf("Please enter student #%d last name : ", i);
        scanf("%79s", students[i].last_name);
        printf("Please enter student #%d id : ", i);
        scanf("%79s", students[i].id);
        printf("Please enter student #%d average : ", i);
        scanf("%f", &students[i].average);
        fprintf(students_file, "#%d.\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %f\n", i, students[i].id,  students[i].first_name, students[i].last_name, students[i].average);
    }
```

to:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < students_num; i++)      /* Note the for loop range */
    {
        printf("Please enter student #%d first name : ", i+1);  /* Just added "1" to the value for human readability */
        scanf("%79s", students[i].first_name);
        printf("Please enter student #%d last name : ", i+1);
        scanf("%79s", students[i].last_name);
        printf("Please enter student #%d id : ", i+1);
        scanf("%79s", students[i].id);
        printf("Please enter student #%d average : ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &students[i].average);
        fprintf(students_file, "#%d.\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %f\n", i+1, students[i].id,  students[i].first_name, students[i].last_name, students[i].average);
    }
```

properly stores the entered data within the structure array.  And the data is then outputted to the file properly.

Following is a test run with the refactored code.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/StudentFile/bin/Release$ ./StudentFile 
How many students do you have ? : 
3
Please enter student #1 first name : mani
Please enter student #1 last name : aghaie
Please enter student #1 id : 1383ma
Please enter student #1 average : 19.72
Please enter student #2 first name : arash
Please enter student #2 last name : hamidi
Please enter student #2 id : 1384ah
Please enter student #2 average : 14.27
Please enter student #3 first name : pourya
Please enter student #3 last name : ghorbani
Please enter student #3 id : 1382pg
Please enter student #3 average : 16.52
```

And viewing the text data in the file presented the following results.

```
number     id       firstname       lastname        average
#1.  1383ma  mani    aghaie  19.719999
#2.  1384ah  arash   hamidi  14.270000
#3.  1382pg  pourya  ghorbani    16.520000
```

So, to recap, always be cognizant that arrays start at element zero ("0").

Give that a try.